# To find the PMF of $Z=E[X \mid Y]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability

Consider the joint PMF of discrete random variables shown below:
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline & Y=0 & Y=1 & Y=2 \\
\hline X=0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{8} \\
\hline X=1 & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Define $Z=E[X \mid Y]$, find PMF of $Z$

My try:
It is known that $Z$ is random variable and is a function of $Y$.
First i tried to find the conditional PMF $P(X=x \mid Y=y)$

For that we need marginal PMF of $Y$ which is:
$$P(Y=y)= \begin{cases}\frac{7}{24}, & y=0 \\ \frac{8}{24}, & y=1 \\ \frac{9}{24}, & y=2\end{cases}$$
But i am stuck now?

Comment: What is $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=0]$? $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=1]$? $\mathbb E[X \mid Y=2]$?  Doing the easy one, you can can say $\mathbb P(Z=\frac12)=\frac13$

Comment: Are you stuck calculating the conditional PMF? It is just a variant of conditional probability: $P(X = x\ |\ Y = y) = \frac{P(X = x \text{ and } Y = y)}{P(Y = y)}$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others in comments,

$P(X=x|Y=y) = \dfrac{P((X =x) \cap (Y=y))}{P(Y=y)}$

$P(X = 1| Y = 0) = \dfrac 1 8 / \dfrac 7 {24} = \dfrac 3 7$

You already obtained, $P(Y = 0) = \dfrac{7}{24}$

$E(X| Y = 0) = 0 \cdot P(X = 0| Y = 0) + 1 \cdot P(X = 1| Y = 0)$

So, $Z = \dfrac{3}{7} ~ $ with probability $\dfrac{7}{24}$ or $ \displaystyle P\left(Z = \dfrac{3}{7}\right) = \frac{7}{24}$

Similarly find $Z = E(X| Y = 1)$ with probability $P(Y=1)$ and $Z = E(X| Y = 2)$ with probability $P(Y = 2)$